# why java BufferedReader miss output

Tags: java

I got error from my code,

```
BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

System.out.print("a    = ");
int a=in.read();
System.out.print("b    = ");
int b=in.read();

System.out.print("    = "+a);
System.out.print("b    = "+b);
```

i try to input 1,
and i dont understand why the result like this?

```
a    = 1

b    =     = 49b    = 13
```

Where is the second input going?

Comment: in.read() reads one character. Pressing Enter will send one or two characters, depending on your operating system;  you must read those as well.

Comment: oke, i understand, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
a = in.readLine();
System.out.print("b    = ");
String b=in.readLine();
int aInt = Integer.valueOf(a);
int bInt = Integer.valueOf(a);
System.out.print("a    = "+aInt);
System.out.print("b    = "+bInt);
```

`read()` reads character by character, so newline will be counted as new character.  To read more about it you can read [here](http://java2learn.com/file-io/bufferedwriter-bufferedreader/).